# Cannot load your from

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

What could be wrong? He says tour is not found, but I check the variable tour kml file which contains my tour. Can you help?

```
var ge;
var la;
var tour = null;
var placemark;
google.load("earth", "1");
var control = 1;
var href;

function init() {
    google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCallback, failureCallback);
}

function initCallback(instance) {
    ge = instance;
    ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
    // IMPORTAZIONE FILE KML REGIONI
    var url = 'http://web.uniparthenope.it/~0124000489/tw-2013/place.kml';
    google.earth.fetchKml(ge, url, finished);
    // ZOOM ITALIA
    look();
    // add a navigation control
    ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);
    // DISABILITO I LAYERS
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, false);
    ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_ROADS, false);
    // CARICO IL TOUR DELLA CAMPANIA
    href = 'http://web.uniparthenope.it/~0124000489/tw-2013/campania.kml';
    google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, function (kmlObject) {
        if (!kmlObject) {
            // wrap alerts in API callbacks and event handlers
            // in a setTimeout to prevent deadlock in some browsers
            setTimeout(function () {
                alert('Bad or null KML.');
            }, 0);
            return;
        }
        // Show the entire KML file in the plugin.
        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
        // Walk the DOM looking for a KmlTour
        walkKmlDom(kmlObject, function () {
            if (this.getType() == 'KmlTour') {
                tour = this;
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
    // ATTENDO UN EVENTO 
    google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getWindow(), 'click', function (e) {
        // VERIFICO SE E' STATO CLICCATO UN PLACEMARK
        var target = e.getTarget();
        if (target.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark') {
            //CANCELLO L'AZIONE DI DEFAULT
            e.preventDefault();
            // ESEGUO IL TOUR
            playTour();
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('installed-plugin-version').innerHTML =
        ge.getPluginVersion().toString();
}

function failureCallback(errorCode) {}

function playTour() {
    if (control == 1) {
        addSampleButton('Exit Tour', exitTour);
        control++;
    }
    if (!tour) {
        alert('No tour found!');
        return;
    }
    ge.getTourPlayer().setTour(tour);
    ge.getTourPlayer().play();
}

function exitTour() {
    ge.getTourPlayer().setTour(null);
    look();
}

function look() {
    var la = ge.createLookAt('');
    la.set(42.5, 12.5,
        0, // altitude
        ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND,
        0, // heading
        0, // straight-down tilt
        1500000 // range (inverse of zoom)
    );
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);
}

function finished(object) {
    if (!object) {
        // wrap alerts in API callbacks and event handlers
        // in a setTimeout to prevent deadlock in some browsers
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert('Bad or null KML.');
        }, 0);
        return;
    }
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(object);
}
```

Comment: Having an empty line every second line makes your code hard to read. Proper code formatting enables others to understand the code more easily.

Comment: It looks like you are calling `playTour` before `tour` was set, i.e. before the callback for `google.earth.fetchKml` was executed. Make sure it cannot be called before the data was loaded.